# alt attribute for thumbnail image that links to the original file

Tags: seo, html, alt-attribute, thumbnail

I have a wallpaper gallery page that displays small thumbnails, when clicked it opens the original full size image for a user to download it.
Will adding `alt` attribute to the thumbnails make the original full size photo appear in google images when searched for? or Google will show the small thumbnail photos? I do intend to achieve the first option.

```
<div class="thumb">
<a href="images/wallpaper.jpg">
<img src="images/wallpaper-small.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement your task, I recommend that you use structured data markup as **[ImageObject](http://schema.org/ImageObject)**, for example:

```
<div class="thumb" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
<a href="images/wallpaper.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl">
<figure>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption">The large image</figcaption>
    <img src="images/wallpaper-small.jpg"itemprop="thumbnail" alt= The thumbnail of large of the same image>
</figure>
</a>
</div>
```

Installing a link without text information about its content is a bad solution. So I added this to your code. You can play with the attributes of this class yourself. Be sure to check your result on the **[Google tester](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)**.

Comment: Thank you, I will do further research about ImageObject and structured data, because I don't really understand this method at the moment. Thank you.

Comment: See additionally information about structured data https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data and  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/prototype

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented this method and it worked. I also added an image sitemap to help the process.

Comment: @MEGA Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The `alt` tag is just for a textual description of the image.  It can be used by screenreaders for visually impaired people or as image metadata by web crawlers.